# How to obtain only 3 results specified by 3 ID's from a MySQL table using the powerful Yii Framework and it's CActiveRecord/CDbCriteria compontents?

Tags: php, search, activerecord, criteria, yii

I'm wondering how can I find these records using the `CActiveRecord` / `CDbCriteria` in Yii:

```
[table]         
 id | value     
 ---------------
  1 | horses    
  2 | snakes    
  3 | panteras  
  4 | commandos
```

As I said, I want only the three first witch I will specify in the right order: 1, 2 and 3.

How is this possible to achieve in Yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yourmodel()::model()->findAll(array(
'criteria' => id <= 4)
);

if the ids will be non consecutive, use addInCondition to the cdbcriteria object.

Comment: Only the 3 first: `yourmodel()::model()->findAll(array( 'criteria' => id < 4) );`

Comment: WTF? That isn't even legitimate PHP syntax!